# Android Studio gradle-###-bin.zip vs. gradle-###-all.zip

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

One developer on my team has some setting in Android Studio that replaces the `distributionUrl` entry in `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` to use the `gradle-###-all.zip`, while my Android Studio changes it back to `gradle-###-bin.zip`.

Basically, my diff always looks like:

`-distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.12-all.zip
+distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.12-bin.zip`

This is annoying.  What setting is it, and how do I change it?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

`gradle-1.12-all.zip` file will have binaries, sources, and documentation.
`gradle-1.12-bin.zip` will have only binaries(That should be enough as you don't need any samples/docs)

If you want to know about gradle wrapper, please check this
http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html

Comment: Thanks, that's informative, but I'm looking for the Android Studio setting/preference/config.  Any ideas?

Comment: Same @San and @Jeff. I'm using IntelliJ and I need to know the `build.gradle` or IntelliJ configuration setting so that when `gradle wrapper` is run it sets the `distributionUrl` from `gradle-4.1-bin.zip` to `gradle-4.1-all.zip`.

Comment: @anon58192932 You need to extend the wrapper task and define `distributionType = DistributionType.ALL`, see https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.wrapper.Wrapper.html

Answer (score 13):

If you and the other developer want a uniform experience, place this code in your `build.gradle` file

```
wrapper {
    distributionType = Wrapper.DistributionType.ALL
}
```

This will make `./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version 5.6` automatically append `-all` instead of `-bin`

For build.gradle.kts:

```
tasks.wrapper {
    distributionType = Wrapper.DistributionType.ALL
}
```

Like @San said, `-all` will have binaries, sources, and documentation, while `-bin` will just have the binaries.

Answer (score 9):

From what I've seen Android Studio recommends to use gradle-*-all.zip and even provides a "quick fix" to change that. On the other hand, the command ./gradlew wrapper sets up the wrapper using gradle-*-bin.zip, overwriting the previous setting. Make sure nobody is calling "./gradlew wrapper" automatically.

Comment: Agree, the tip says: "You can configure Gradle wrapper to use distribution with sources.  It will provide IDE with Gradle API/DSL documentation."  If you apply the tip, it changes to `-all`.

Comment: I'm not seeing this in IntelliJ unfortunately but I'm wondering if we can set this in the main `build.gradle` file in order to set it across the board for all users?

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that the `-bin` version contains only the runtime and no sample code and documentation. [1](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html)

It actually makes sense to go for the `-bin` version: it is smaller and you're unlikely to need the `-all` version unless you're debugging Gradle scripts. For this reason, the lint warning to go for the `-all` version has been removed. Also, new projects are generated with the `-bin` version by default.

There is [a ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-203597) to let IntelliJ download the sources when you need them (after which there *really* isn't a reason for the `-all` version), but it hasn't been implemented yet.